# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token è in AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function that calls a php file:

```
function insertdati(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "getDataModTrad.php",
        type: "POST",
        asyn: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The php file:

```
<?php
echo("è");
?>
```

But I receive an error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token è
```

I've tried to change `echo("è")` to `echo utf8_encode("è")` but the error
continues to appear! Can someone tell me what I have to do?

Comment: is the page you're making the ajax request from set to use utf-8 charset in the header?

Comment: yes i used <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to parse it as JSON.

Comment: Try to add `dataType : 'html'`.

Comment: it continue to say error!

Comment: oook!so sorry! thanks to @SLaks! next the console.log i call another function whit the result that have a JSON.parse! :( so sorry and thanks so much!